# clear Activity Stack when user Logs in

Tags: android, android-intent

There are a lot of topics on this post. But i couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Let me describe my `activity` stack first.

> SplashScreen->A->Login->Home.

What i would like to achieve is , when i click on `back` button after logging in to `Home`, i should come out of the application and go to `Home` if i use my application again. For this i am assuming i should clear the activity stack before Home, after i login. I would also like to preserve the activity stack if the user hasn't logged in yet.

I want this to work on or after 2.1

What i have tried already.

1. using `finish()` in `Login` Activity , before calling `startActivity` on `Home`. This will redirect me to A , if i use back button on Home.
2. All variations of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`  and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` . Nothing worked, when i use back button, i am redirected to login screen.

Any suggestions or simple solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using `finish()` in `Login` Activity , before calling `startActivity` on `Home`. This will redirect me to A , if i use back button on Home.

**ok** so use finish on all the activities that you want them to be popped before calling `startActivity`

> go to `Home` if i use my application again

Simply save your login parameters in `SharedPreference` and from A startActivity Home directly if login successful.

Comment: how do i call finish on all activities? , by overriding startActivityForResult() ?

Comment: no ... you said using finish in Login Activity before calling startActivity on Home works fine and the back button redirects to A instead of the Login Activity... So in all your unwanted activities do the same.. for example if you dont want A, use finish() before calling startActivity on Login

Comment: but i want to preserve my stack if the user hasn't logged in yet.

Comment: ok so the best practice would be to use results ... so start your activities using startActivityForResult! When you want to end activity use an appropriate result (using `setResult()` before `finish()`) in the activity before you could use this result to take the appropriate action using onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to make use of `BroadcastReceiver` aswell if you want to try that route.

In your "SplashScreen" and "A" activities, in the `onCreate` method you can create and register and `IntentFilter` and a `BroadcastReceiver` like so:

Assuming you have a global variable called `broadcastReceiver`

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("ACTION_LOGIN");

                this.broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        finish();
                    }
                };

                registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Also don't forget to unregister your receiver in the `onDestroy` method (this is to prevent memory leaks in the program):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Now in your "Login" activity, once the user has successfully logged in, you can broadcast a message to all the registered receivers, which will finish those activites in the back stack:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction("ACTION_LOGIN");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Your SplashScreen and A activities will now be finished.